# How to play sound on Xcode build success or error?

Tags: xcode, audio, build

I want to play a `success.mp3` sound on Xcode build success and a `failure.mp3` on Xcode build failure. How can I do so? However, I can play sound after build finishes using this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59498554/1084174) but need to distinguish success and failure cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at: Preferences > Behaviours

[image: Preferences page with behaviors for specific events like build succeeds, including actions like "play sound"]